# Embed YouTube livestream or most recent livestream

Tags: youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm building a Joomla site for our church and I would like to have a page where our users can go to see our livestream when it's live, but if it's not currently live I would like for the most recent livestream to be the video that will be available to play.

I have the first part:

This will only currently work if we are live. If I go there right now it says "Stream offline" and just has the loading circle.

I do not currently have any additional code that includes our API which could be part of the problem too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We have exactly the same use case in our church. For elderly people we'd like to distribute Android TV boxes that have e.g. a macro-app installed that launches the current live stream automatically.